# What is the real meaning of mass in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mass

I know the meaning of mass in classical physics, the ratio of force and acceleration. But what do we mean when we talk about the mass of an electron in quantum mechanics?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [The interpretation of mass in quantum field theories](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56903/50583), [Is mass an observable in Quantum Mechanics?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19424/50583)

Comment: Are you referring to inertial mass or gravitational mass?

Comment: INERTIAL MASS Of course

Comment: In the rest frame of a particle that is an eigenstate of energy, ${mc^2}\over{\hbar}$ is the frequency (radians per sec) that a free (no potentials) particle's wave function oscillates at as time progresses.