# Mass term in field Lagrangian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, mass, field-theory, feynman-diagrams

In the Klein-Gordon or in the Dirac Lagrangian density, the mass term is quadratic in the field. The other way around, I have heard a quadratic term in a general Lagrangian density be referred to as a mass term. Why is that, and what does that mean exactly?

I also think I understood that Feynman diagrams don't contain vertices that are connected to only two edges, because that would correspond to a quadratic term, which is a mass term and is treated differently. Does that make sense? How?

Comment: Duplicate of [The interpretation of mass in quantum field theories](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56903/50583) and [Why is mass the quadratic term in a Lagrangian?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9000/50583)

Comment: @ACuriousMind They are certainly similar, maybe essentially identical, but the answers there are not answers to this questions (though it may be that I simply misunderstand the answers). From the answers there it would seem to me that for particular Lagrangians the quadratic term should be interpreted as mass. What I would like to understand is if a quadratic term in general can be interpreted as a mass term, if so, why, or is it only called so by analogy?